# Springboot org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry class discrepancy

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, server

I have a legacy application which is using **Struts-1** and **Hibernate-4**. Now I've introduced **Spring-Boot** in the application and added the corresponding dependencies in pom. But while I'm running the application, it's getting an error.

The `pom.xml` I used is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project1 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <description>Rest Multipart API</description>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- cxw Adding this per to fix SOAP issues in new Eclipse -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cxw - replacing this -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-discovery/commons-discovery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId> <artifactId>jxl</artifactId> 
            <version>2.6</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- cxw - replacing this entirely with the following -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.mail</groupId> <artifactId>mail</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.7</version> <scope>provided</scope> -->

        <!-- cxw debug - removing exclusion for use in new eclipse -->
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <artifactId>activation</artifactId> <groupId>javax.activation</groupId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->

        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>Query</groupId>
            <artifactId>QueryObject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>Query</groupId>
            <artifactId>QueryObjectLink</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>struts</groupId> <artifactId>struts</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jasper -->
        <!-- cxw - replacing THIS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.96</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.4</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> <artifactId>jasper</artifactId> 
            <version>6.0.32</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/xmlparser Added
            e911Home.jsp error dependancy with SmfActionTypesUtil -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlparser</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>JGo</groupId>
            <artifactId>JGo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>JGo</groupId>
            <artifactId>JGoLayout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.enterprisedt/edtFTPj -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.enterprisedt</groupId>
            <artifactId>edtFTPj</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey/jersey-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ########### jDevWebservice Copy(Remove later) ############# -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdev.webservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsclient</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ########### jDevWebservice Copy(Remove later) ############# -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdev.webservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- if you are using Jersey client specific features without the server 
            side -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.smallmind/scheduling-quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.smallmind</groupId>
            <artifactId>scheduling-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.smallmind/scheduling-quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.smallmind</groupId>
            <artifactId>scheduling-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->


        <!-- Introduction of SpringBoot start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Introduction of SpringBoot end -->
        <!-- ######################## -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file=true</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <finalName>Project1</finalName>
    </build>


</project>
```

I'm geting in the console :

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2021-03-26 23:10:20.923  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] com.sprint.neo.restApi.E911Application   : Starting E911Application using Java 1.8.0_201 on IN-00215004 with PID 19596 (C:\prosenjit\projects2\e911_current_release_V2\target\classes started by edttprs in C:\prosenjit\projects2\e911_current_release_V2)
2021-03-26 23:10:20.928  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] com.sprint.neo.restApi.E911Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-rt\2.3.2\jaxws-rt-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.annotation-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.jws-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.ws-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.soap-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/FastInfoset.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/gmbal.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/ha-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/management-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/mimepull.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-asm.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-basic-tools.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-basic.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-dynamic.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-tf-tools.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/pfl-tf.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/policy.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/saaj-impl.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/stax-ex.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/stax2-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/streambuffer.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/txw2.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2/woodstox-core.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\ha\ha-api\3.1.12\ha-api-3.1.12.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/hk2.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/hk2-core.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/class-model.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/config.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/tiger-types.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/bean-validator.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/jtype.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/auto-depends.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/javax.inject.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/asm-all-repackaged.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/hk2-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/osgi-resource-locator.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.12/javax.inject.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-tools\2.3.2\jaxws-tools-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-tools/2.3.2/jaxws-rt.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-tools/2.3.2/jaxb-xjc.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-tools/2.3.2/jaxb-jxc.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.3.2/jaxb-impl.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-jxc\2.3.2\jaxb-jxc-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-jxc/2.3.2/jaxb-impl.jar,file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-jxc/2.3.2/jaxb-xjc.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.068  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\edttprs\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.2.1\c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.2.1/mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar
2021-03-26 23:10:21.069  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-03-26 23:10:21.069  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-03-26 23:10:22.472  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\prosenjit\software\project_software\maven\binary\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adaptiva\AdaptivaClient\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%ANT_PATH%\bin;%XML_BEANS%\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\edttprs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\edttprs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\edttprs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\edttprs\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\edttprs\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;;C:\eclipse;;.
2021-03-26 23:10:22.735  WARN 19596 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
2021-03-26 23:10:22.753  INFO 19596 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-26 23:10:22.802 ERROR 19596 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:184)

The following method did not exist:

    org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V

The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.96/tomcat-coyote-7.0.96.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.41/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry: file:/C:/Users/edttprs/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.96/tomcat-coyote-7.0.96.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry
```

and I'm running the below code snippet :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

Please suggest how run the application successfully. Is there any dependency version mismatch in the pom, for which this error is showing?? I got few hints in other questions in stackoverflow like : [disableRegistry() doesn't exist (org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833809/disableregistry-doesnt-exist-org-apache-tomcat-util-modeler-registry) OR, [Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139869/correct-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatib) , but those don't help in my scenario. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Are there any class that calls tomcat related classes? you are currently using embeded tomcat so the version of tomcat has been changed

Comment: In the pom, I have tomcat related dependencies : `org.apache.tomcat`. Is it causing the error? But if I remove those, then also I'm getting error.

Comment: Actually your code base is too old. I have worked with struts and others but your spring boot version is too new to be used. The tomcat is really new for those libraries. You can consider to refactor your code base. Without rewriting it is really hard to convert it to spring boot. Best approach can be lower your spring boot version. Also remove tomcat related dependencies they are old.